# JavaScript to retrieve contents of span element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid

My task is to output the contents of my div Id's in a formatted rectangle.  I have everything working correctly for my 'p' elements but can't seem to figure out how to get the 'span' elements.  I know it should be easy but I've run out of ideas (maybe because it's 3am). The code below is working for me, but I can't figure out where to add the 'span'.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>DOM Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 >DOM Example</h1>

        <div id="weekday"> weekdays
            <p>Monday</p>
            <p>Tuesday</p>
            <p>Wednesday</p>
            <p>Thursday</p>
            <p>Friday</p>
        </div>
        <div id="weekend"> weekends
            <p>Saturday</p>
            <p>Sunday</p>
        </div>
        <div id="summer"> summer
            <span> June</span>
            <span> July</span>
            <span> August</span>
        </div>
            <p>Thank you</p>
            <p>Have a nice day</p>
        <div id="rectangleDiv"> 

        </div>
        <script>

        var input = prompt("Input weekend, weekday, or summer");

        var matches = [];
        var searchEles = document.getElementById(input).children;
        for(var i = 0; i < searchEles.length; i++) {
                if(searchEles[i].tagName == 'p' || searchEles[i].tagName == 'P') {
                    matches.push(searchEles[i].innerText);
                }
            }

         var rectangle = document.getElementById("rectangleDiv");
        rectangle.setAttribute("style","width:250px;height:200px;background-color:cyan;color:blue;border-color:red;border-size:3px;border-style:solid;");
        var i;
        for(i=0;i<matches.length;i++) {
            rectangle.innerHTML +=matches[i]+"<br>";
        }

        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you consider using jQuery? If so there is an easy solution

Comment: Instead of `.children`, use `.getElementsByTagName('span')` or `.querySelectorAll('span')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check for `span` tag name too, since you can have either `p` or `span` as children:

```
if (searchEles[i].tagName == 'P' || searchEles[i].tagName == 'SPAN') {
    matches.push(searchEles[i].innerText);
}
```

By the way, [`Element.tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) is always uppercase string, so no need to check for lower `p` and `span`.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ax5pn09L/

Comment: Best answer so far, but just for own culture : Why does the tagname 'SPAN' has to be in capital letters to make it work ?

Comment: @Harijoe Because HTML Element tagName property is the uppercase string. It can be lowecase for XML documents.

Comment: Ah I've just found a more accurate answer : "In XHTML (or any other XML format), "span" would be alerted. In HTML, "SPAN" would be alerted instead.". Thanks anyway.

Comment: Beautiful!  I didn't know about the uppercase and that explains why when added 'span' to the || code it didn't work.

Comment: @user2948381 Good, glad it was useful!

Answer (score 0):

Try using
`document.getElementsByTagName('span`)`

Or
`querySelectorAll('span')`

But be aware that you wont get a string as return

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the same way you got the text from the "p" elements, add a check on "span".

jsfiddle code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/fxatn8kv/

```
if(searchEles[i].tagName == 'p' || searchEles[i].tagName == 'P' || searchEles[i].tagName.toLowerCase() == 'span')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.querySelectorAll('p, span')` like so:

[JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/h3nanehk/2/)

```
var input = document.getElementById(prompt("Input weekend, weekday, or summer"));

var spans = input.querySelectorAll('p, span');

for(var i = 0, l = spans.length; i < l; i++){
    console.log(spans[i].textContent || spans[i].innerText);
}
```

Comment: The OP is using a mixture of  `<p>` and `<span>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Universal solution is to find elements by class

```
if(searchEles[i].className == 'elementToFind')
```

and then process result as needed. It will find all the results at once for summer will be: "June July August"

```
<div id="summer"> summer
  <strong class="elementToFind"> June</span>
  <h2 class="elementToFind"> July</span>
  <span class="elementToFind"> August</span>
</div>
```